# How to show webpage sized to a particular viewport width, based on the current actual screen width

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, responsive-design

I'm looking to show my webpage layout at a smaller width (e.g. at viewport width=1200), for screens with high resolutions (e.g. The device's viewport width is 2160px).

Reason is because on high resolutions, the page elements become tiny and I want an efficient way to show the page elements at their right size.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question? can you not just resize your browser?

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you are asking but there is a website called [resizemybrowser](http://resizemybrowser.com/) that could help. The only other things I can suggest is a adding this meta tag to the html of the app `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,width=device-width,user-scalable=no" />`